# How to filter value based on Date range

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a react project. And the requirement is to create a dropdown with hardcoded values as last 30 days last 60 days, last 90 days and last 120 days and on basis of the option selected I have to filter the json data and display it.

I have tried the following so far:

```
let onAddDates = (e) => {
if (e !== null) {
  setAddDates(e.value);
}

}

function createDateFormula  (addDates) {
  
  if(addDates == 'Last 30 days'){
    FilterDate =  new Date(new Date().setDate(CurrentDate.getDate() - 30));
  }
  if(addDates == 'Last 60 days'){
    FilterDate =  new Date(new Date().setDate(CurrentDate.getDate() - 60));
  }
  if(addDates == 'Last 90 days'){
    FilterDate =  new Date(new Date().setDate(CurrentDate.getDate() - 90));
  }
  if(addDates == 'Last 120 days'){
    FilterDate =  new Date(new Date().setDate(CurrentDate.getDate() - 120));
  }
}
function handleAllDatesFilter(dataToFilter) {
  createDateFormula();
  if(dataToFilter && dataToFilter!=claimHistoryConstants.emptyString) {
    
    
    if(FilterDate && CurrentDate) {
      return dataToFilter.filter((localData) => {
        console.log("From Date: "+(FilterDate)+" To Date: "+JSON.stringify(CurrentDate));
        const date=new Date(localData.fnCreationDate).getDate();
        const year=new Date(localData.fnCreationDate).getFullYear();
        const month=new Date(localData.fnCreationDate).getMonth()+1;
        const localDate=`${month}/${date}/${year}`;
        return (new Date(localDate) >= FilterDate) && 
        (new Date(localDate) <= CurrentDate);              
      });
    } else {
      console.log("Null");
      return dataToFilter;            
    }
  }
}
const AllDatesOptions = [
{ value: 'Last 30 days', label: 'Last 30 days' },
{ value: 'Last 60 days', label: 'Last 60 days' },
{ value: 'Last 90 days', label: 'Last 90 days' },
{ value: 'Last 120 days', label: 'Last 120 days' }
 ]

  <Select className="AdvancedFilterText"
          ref={allDatesRef}
          options={AllDatesOptions}
          isSearchable
          placeholder={"ALL DATES"}
          onChange={event => onAddDates(event)}>
          
        </Select>
```

Comment: you have declared your `createDateFormula(addDates)` but when you use the function you dont pass nothing to it

Comment: Where has ```handleAllDatesFilter function```  been triggered? You should trigger the filter function for example at ```onAddDates function```

Comment: @AndriNic I passed the value now but still the data is not getting filtered

Comment: @Mehrnoosh onAddDates method is storing the value that we selected from the dropdown

Comment: @HarshitaArya If `onAddDates` does only that the the `handleAllDatesFilter` function is not triggered anywhere in your code

Comment: @AbdullahKhaled It is triggered when I click on the Apply button

Comment: @HarshitaArya `FilterDate` seems to some sort of global variable your react app won't rerender until you made a state change. Can you give us more context about your problem?

Comment: @AbdullahKhaled The function handleAllDatesFilter is not filtering the json data .